How to determine thermodynamic state?
I'm an undergraduate and what I learned in my class is that for thermodynamic equilibrium, at least two variables has to be decided such as $G(P,T)$ or $S(U, V)$
But if thermodynamic variables naturally move to minimize $U$ or maximize $S$ at equilibrium like the picture under, doesn't that mean we only need one variable to determine thermodynamic state or equilibrium? What would be the concept that I'm misleading? Is there a difference between thermodynamic state and equilibrium? 

There is no difference between thermodynamic state and equilibrium.  If the system is not at equilibrium, other parameters are involved.  Also, at chemical equilibrium, the thermodynamic functions also depend on concentration of the various species present.

I kinda get the concept but above picture confuses me.  Will it be okay to understand as two variables are fixed, the other variable as a result is fixed, which is the equilibrium and any state(?) deviated from will move to the one? And for state and equilibrium, does it mean system that is not in equilibrium can not be stated?

I really don’t follow what you are saying.  Are you familiar with this phrase rule?

The system only moves to minimize $U$ or maximize $S$ when they are out of equilibrium. When they reach equilibrium, they have a fixed $U$ and $S$, and we need to specify exactly what those fixed values are, along with other variables if needed, to determine what macrostate we are in.

Firstly, thanks. But I still have confusions. Does every point on the parabolic surface above corresponds to the equilibrium? or is it only the point A on the parabola in the first picture, that intersects with constant U0 plane, an equilibrium for constant U0? So that if there's any state on the parabola, will it move to point A to maximize S?
